# Linq to SQL Insert Error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> An attempt has been made to Attach or
>   Add an entity that is not new, perhaps
>   having been loaded from another
>   DataContext.  This is not supported.

This is the error message I am getting when I try to run the following, roughly:

```
1 DataContext db = new DataContext();
2 o = new object();
3 o.association = db.GetAssociatedObject(pId);
4 db.objects.InsertOnSubmit(o);
5 db.SubmitChanges();
```

This code creates a new object, populates an association with an existing object, then inserts the new object. When I comment out line 3+4, the error goes away. What causes the error? Can I not do an insert with associated objects?

Comment: what happens when u comment out line 4, only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading. This is a bit more complicated, but I found the error.

I have a method that is trying to save a detached object, and create associations for it.
This method creates a new attached copy of the object and copies all the members. It then creates the association.

Say I have object A that is detached. My method tries to read it from database so that I have the attached version of it. Say this is object A. A is being updated with all the members that changed.
A needs to get an association with objects of type C, via a many-to-many relationship called B:  A <= B => C

I assigned the detached copy of A to B. This caused the exception. Once I assigned the correct instance of A, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are maintaining a bidirectional relationship between o and its associated object. When you tell the `DataContext` to Insert o, its associated object is duplicated in the DataContext's object tracking graph (one time as loaded and another time as Insert for o).

Commenting out line 4 should resolve the issue, but leave you with a correct association between o and o.association.

Comment: Well, the weird thing is, the same exception is thrown when I comment either line 3 or 4. Only when I comment out both, I get no exception.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I had the same suspicion, but I am pretty sure I am doing this in other places where I don't get this error. How else would I go about establishing a foreign key relationship for a new object ... ? Of course does the object on the other side already exist. Since I am loading it in the same DC before I establish the relationship, Linq should know that it already exists.

Comment: This is actually a many-to-many association that I am trying to create.
So, both objects exists, just the association needs to be inserted.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that both objects were actually transient (because one is new'ed up). If asking questions like this you should provide full detail so people can help you.